# what happened to universe factory?

Tags: discussion, blog

I recently discovered it but have noticed there has been little to no activity since mid to late 2019, and a few series are cut off. I was wondering why this cutoff happened and or what could be done to fix it.

Answer (score 9):

At this point, I'm (technically) the guy who runs it.

Back when we started [Universe Factory](https://medium.com/universe-factory) in 2015, we had a whole lot of activity - lots of interest, lots of authors, lost of posts. People gradually drifted away, in many cases from Worldbuilding Stack Exchange itself, something that was exacerbated by a network-wide crisis this past fall (see [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/333965/274942) for a bit of a timeline). Most of the most prolific authors have left over the last couple of years, and while we still get some submissions once in a blue moon, it feels a bit like a ghost ship. I've had an idea or two floating around for a bit, but I can't guarantee it'll become anything coherent anytime soon.

That said - we are open to new authors, new posts, and new ideas! Periodically, I've thought about putting together a meta post asking for new submissions, and if new users like yourself are aware of the blog - well, maybe there's enough interest. What I *can* say is that we would love to get new (and old) voices in. It's just a matter of figuring out how the heck we do that.

Comment: Hey I'd like to participate in it sometime :)

Comment: well i am working on one world a lot i might add a series on it but some stories like the golden sails are just cut off the most recent post or whatever you wanna call it was in  january this year as far as i can see. Some people are easy to find like you and others are not, some can be found but they quit. so i know there's not much we can do.

Comment: @Topcode, Golden Sails was my story, and unfortunately I sorta just lost interest, so that's what happened to that story.

Comment: @gryphon well ya i know that, like i said a lot of the people have quit or otherwise stopped. Btw i do really like the story you made.

Comment: I'm one of the ones who posted a couple stories there! Haven't recently, though. The main issue I see with Medium is that there is so very little interaction there!  (I don't mean "claps" -- that's not interaction.) I mean comments or responses. Several authors have written veritable dissertations on Medium, and in all these years, they've gotten maybe 10 claps and 0 comments. I at least found that somewhat disheartening.

Comment: Alright, just submitted another story. Maybe we can get the Factory started up again?

Comment: @elemtilas could you maybe link it, i cant seem to find it

Comment: @Topcode -- It's been submitted, but it seems our Editorial Board needs to approve all submissions.

Comment: @elemtilas alright, ill be waiting

Comment: So the big issue here is that the "Editorial Board" is currently just me - I'm the only current editor; Secespitus had stepped up into the role as well but is, I believe, inactive. This is something that we're gonna have to fix, though to be honest, if we have to fix it because there's suddenly a rise in interest - well, that's a good problem to have. I'll write up a meta post in the next day or so to maybe try to get more folks onboard. And, yes, I've finally gotten the time to look over the post, and it's up now. Nice writing! cc @elemtilas

Comment: @HDE226868 i mean there are plenty of users here who could help

Comment: @HDE226868 - (:  Many thanks to the "Editorial Board"!  I could help if you need a coeditor / curator or whatever.  Question: any idea why the story doesn't show up (for me at least!) in Universe Factory? I can access it through my profile, but I don't see it under Fiction. Or any of the other tabs. Did I do something wrong?

Comment: I'm still writing *The Juggernaut* on and off... but due to the inactivity of the place, and Monica moving on to other things, I thought that it was defunct.  I'll submit the next chapter soon.  The main problem is that I can't just copy and paste to Medium, when I do, it dumps the formatting, and I have to reapply it.

Comment: If you wanted another editor/curator, I could help out too.

Comment: @MontyWild -  The formatting in Medium does kind of suck.

Comment: @Topcode thanks!  I'm glad at least a few people liked it.

Comment: @Gryphon of course people liked it, its clear you put a lot of work and time into it to make it good.

Comment: @Topcode well, if people did like it, I may see if I can dig up my notes and at least finish the Golden Sails bit.

Comment: @Gryphon really, well i think many people would enjoy seeing series coming back, if only for a short time or just to finish it