# Is Universe Factory still alive?

Tags: discussion, blog, community

It's simple, for a while now, Universe Factory (both the room and the site) shows no signs of life, which makes me sad.

Now, I'm not saying I have much to post, in fact, making a 4-minute read exhausts me more than it should. Still, I think I might write something, even more as an experiment.

**So, what's the Factory's current status?**

Comment: I might be wrong, but my experience is that Monica Ciello was one of the primary evangelists for Universe Factory. My sincere thanks to everyone who's still working to keep Universe Factory alive, but it was nevertheless collateral damage to the actions that led to our loss of Monica. It's unbelievable how much of the glue that held a bunch of non-technical Stacks together was hers. It's now up to us to fill some amazing shoes.

Comment: @JBH I know this is a stupid idea, but here I go: In my opinion, Monica, the SE staff, AND the SE community should just apologize to each other, stop with the drama, and go on like it never happened. Erase the apology, give back that mod status, add in some gender neutrality guidelines (the mods' jobs have always required them to be able to discern intent, hence, their role hasn't been overtaken by GPT-3 (yet)). When I arrived here, I was like "Well, I'm the most controversial and/or political figure" But now? I turned away for a moment and now everything is filled with Trump and SJWs!

Comment: I mean, we don't and shouldn't need controversy to survive, we're better than Vaush and Sargon. And while forgiveness isn't to be handed out like candy, if I was incapable of it, my backyard would be filled with so many dead bodies! Corpses for days? Corpses for days.

Comment: This is not okay. Now I'm the apolitical closet-furry, asking about justifications for having my animal folk walk around with minimum clothing, and dragons... lots of dragon-related questions. I just want everything to be exactly like in 2017, when I joined and wrote my first question. Is that a selfish desire? Hecking yes! But I can't keep this good-boy mask on forever, makes me feel like a manipulative bastard.

Comment: I see your point. I also know that you can't have it like it was in 2017 without somehow replacing Monica. Sometimes, life sucks.

Comment: @JBH You're talking about her as if she was dead! I asked my flowers, and they told me, she's nowhere to be found under the ground, i.e: she's still alive.

Comment: @Mephistopheles You neglect psychological effects. Having a cordial relationship with somebody who betrayed your trust so utterly… it'd be nice to have, but it's not something anybody should be expected to do. If you want Monica, head over to [Codidact](https://codidact.com).

Comment: @wizzwizz4 I'd still prefer to have all my eggs in one basket, even if I have to induce mass-amnesia to achieve it.

Comment: @Mephistopheles Well, Codidact has an “import from Stack Exchange” feature, so you could easily move your eggs. :-p But, yeah, mass-amnesia would have to start with removing / adding corrections to the newspaper articles, which still hasn't happened.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 And how many people did it import from here?

Comment: @wizzwizz4 It apparently imported part of me, cause members had also made answers to my questions.

Comment: @Mephistopheles Why Monica would be supposed to apologize for anything?

Comment: @reducingactivity The community should apologize for going overboard with the drama, and SE should apologize for shutting Monica down for the lamest reason ever. I mean, I don't understand why the new CoC was such a big deal back then. Even if it passed, no one would really enforce it or want it to be enforced.

Answer (score 5):

We're still alive! Although we're sorta in low power mode again because of a lack of content.

We had [a bit of a bump in the spring](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7852/627), after which things fell off. At the moment, there's one submission in the queue that I've been meaning to get to since the weekend - I'll hopefully approve that sooner rather than later. But as always, anyone who has an idea for a post is welcome to submit it!

Comment: That might be me. I wanted to test my writing skills (even if a 4-min read took me several days to complete) by writing a fake excerpt.

Comment: @Mephistopheles Ah, okay. Should I not consider it a submission, then?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: I mean, I wrote it so that 1. I could finally use Gyvaris, 2. That other people could review and critique my style. I'm not entirely sure if it's a good fit for Universe Factory,  though the dragon's breath weapon is unconventional, if it is, then you can consider it as my submission.

Comment: In case any outsider is wondering, here's what I was talking about: https://viharmester4.medium.com/so-i-decided-to-try-and-write-an-excerpt-32e875571225

Comment: @Mephistopheles Makes sense, thanks. Let me know when you have a title in mind.

Comment: What kind of title are we talking about? This is a (terrible) writing attempt, so I don't want to blow any of my munition on it. I renamed it to *"An attempt at writing"*. If we need something more descriptive, maybe I could try *An attempt at writing: The Gryphons and a Dragon* (though that sounds a bit dumb).

Comment: So, decided to change the title (again) and do some other touch-ups. What I'm curious about is if my submission is a good fit for Universe Factory.

Comment: @Mephistopheles I think it is! It looks good.

Comment: As in subject matter?

Comment: @Mephistopheles Yeah, absolutely.

Comment: Acknowledged, thanks!

Comment: @HDE226868 i just realized ive been writing part 2 of my story for like half a year, i should probably finish it

Comment: @Topcode Excellent! No hurry, but whenever you complete it, we'd love to see it.

Comment: @HDE226868 well, your in luck, ITS DONE