# Are there no universe factory editors anymore?

Tags: discussion

Around a 10 months ago I made a [post](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7848/what-happened-to-universe-factory) asking about what happened to universe factory. HDE 226868♦ informed me that he was really the only editor left and that activity had died down due to a few things. A short bit after HDE made [another post](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7852/a-call-for-blog-writers-and-editors) asking for more writers and editors. [A](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7855/73498) [few](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7853/73498) [people](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7863/73498) said they could help editing. Although I don't know if anything came of those.

10 days ago I (finally) finished [part 2](https://medium.com/@.topcode./salvage-part-two-of-landed-689363aa2546) of my story I've been writing for universe factory and submitted it to the editorial board, and also left a comment as a reply to one of HDE's comments on a more recent meta post about universe factory.

To date I haven't gotten a reply nor my story approved. Does universe factory no longer have active editors?

Comment: Just a comment for now: It's been a crazy last week and a half for me - I had to get up at 4:30 AM on Tuesday; that kinda encapsulates things in a nutshell. Currently, as I'm the only active editor (I believe?), that means I'm the rate-limiting step to all of this. Apologies for taking so long; I'll try and take a look at the post tomorrow. I think there's also a discussion to be had about getting more folks onboard for editing, and I'm also the rate-limiting step. For me, that's also going to have to be a tomorrow-ish problem.

Comment: @HDE226868 Its no problem, sometimes that happens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Last week was extremely busy for me, and I fell behind on a lot of things, this included. Sorry about that.

I've gone ahead and made the relevant changes:

- The blog post [is now published in Universe Factory](https://medium.com/universe-factory/salvage-part-two-of-landed-689363aa2546?source=collection_home---1------0-----------------------)!
- I've added elemtilas as an editor; let me know if there are any issues there. Turns out Monty Wild already has editing privileges, so they're also covered
- I've updated [the meta post about blog announcements](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4037/627) and set up an item in the community bulletin for the next week - it should show up around 0:00 UTC on February 16.

With the additional folks available for editing, hopefully this sort of thing won't be an issue in the future.

Answer (score 5):

As one of the ones who encouraged you (and Mephistopheles) to post your stories to U.F., I'm glad to hear it's done and in the queue!

As for editors, I know I've expressed interest in being an editor before, and [as I noted in that question](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7852/a-call-for-blog-writers-and-editors), MontyWild also expressed interest. Sadly, I never heard anything else about the call for editors after that time.

The last mention of U.F. was in [November & December last year](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8125/is-universe-factory-still-alive).

Hopefully HDE226868♦ will be able to respond to this!

Comment: well HDE's profile says last seen 16 minutes ago, so hopefully he sees this soon. and 2 minutes after i say this there he is

Comment: @Topcode Making up for lost time, I guess. . . Also, elemtilas, if you're still interested in being an editor, I can add you on Medium tomorrow.

Comment: @HDE226868 -- Still interested!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I'm an editor, however most of my work is done via mobile, and Medium has compatibility problems with mobile platforms in my experience.

I can see work that has been submitted to Universe Factory, but I can't approve it unless I log on to a desktop... and my lack of time on desktops means that I rarely get a chance to do so.